# Is it possible to invoke SQL-injection in Play Framework?

Tags: playframework, sql-injection

I want to use Java Play Framework to write RESTful backend. I've worked only with PHP Language and Android development before.

So I want to know whether the possible typical PHP SQL-injection for Play Framework? If yes, how to defend against them?

Comment: If the framework exposes any way to submit a raw SQL query, then yes -- it's entirely possible.  Frameworks can only do so much to protect people from their own boneheadedness.

Answer (score 5):

Every piece of code can be done bad or wrong, if you'll be stubborn enough you will be able to allow the kids to attack you via params... even with Play.

On the other hand Play (especially ver. 2.x) puts massive effort to type safety, which means that yet at routing level you can prevent simplest attacks i.e you declare every time type of params in url which means that you don't need to check like in PHP `if(intval($_GET['param'])>0)` as you declared it in routing time as an Integer. Play just won't recognize the path with string in this place. sample:

```
GET  /find-user/:id   controllers.Users.find(id: Int)
```

Requires link like `http://domain.tld/find-user/123` and simple inject approach `http://domain.tld/find-user/123 AND 1==1` will give you... 404 page (actually *route not found* by default as you need to handle 404 yourself).

What's more when using ie Java with Ebean - typically even if you build your queries *manually* you can use parametrized placeholders which rises security a muuuch. Last time I made a survey within our project and although I'm not super-hacker... I wasn't able to inject SQL in anyway to even basic queries which were written with the Ebean API.

Finally if you were working with raw `mysql_query("SELECT ...` till now and learned how to prevent injections with Play most probably you can forget additional efforts, just keep eye opened and you'll be safe.

Answer (score 4):

The issue isn't so much with Play but rather with the persistence framework you use within Play. When using Play with Java, you have [JPA](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpy.html) and [EBean](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introduction.html) (though being demoted I believe) supported out of the box, and both have facilities for preventing SQL injection--including when using raw SQL (rather than say JPQL in JPA).

[Here](http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-java-persistence-api-jpa) is a nice resource on preventing SQL injection with JPA.

When using Play with Scala, Slick and Anorm also have similar protections.

But of course, if you go out of your way to write code with vulnerabilities, you will have code with vulnerabilities.